# PhpStorm PHP Annotations and Symfony plugin seem not to work

Tags: symfony, plugins, autocomplete, phpstorm, autosuggest

How can I make PhpStorm help me write blocks/extends and closing tags for them like in Sublime Text 3?

If I write

> block + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

I end up with

> `<block></block>`

I don't have auto suggestions (even though I feel like I should...) so I have to type

```
{% // that turns to {%%}
```

start typing "block", click <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> and pick "block", but even then I get just single

> {% block %} (without endblock)

I have a similar problem with annotations. In Controller if I try to add

`/**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Meth // here I expect to have suggested "@Method" so that I can click enter and have it in place
     */`

but it just sometimes autocomplete the word for me after <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> or allows to pick e.g "Route" and doesn't care about parameters.

I have Symfony plugin and PHP Annotation (which didn't work till I reinstalled it like twice) but now I feel like there is still something wrong. Maybe I turned off some option...?

Comment: PhpStorm doesn't support endblock completion yet, please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19615
As for the @Method completion, I can't reproduce that in 2018.3.3 having both plugins enabled: http://recordit.co/qYkeDaDcFC
You have the Symfony support enabled at Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Symfony, don't you?

Comment: @EugeneMorozov Is it required to sign up on youtrack to vote? Now I get the message that I can't vote in this issue. Yes, I had enabled both of them all the time and today it actually worked with annotation after I reinstalled those plugins again... That's weird, every time after uninstall, reinstall, I restarted PS but it seemed not to catch those changes till now. Also, I can't make PS to auto enable Symfony plugin. I understand that I have two options - turn it on with every project manually or allow to do it auto (I should get info window in the corner?) but sometimes it doesn't appear.

Comment: It is necessary to be logged on to vote on YT, correct.
I just tested the auto-detect functionality on a generic Symfony project, and it threw a notification that it's possible to enable the plugin. Is there a consistently reproducible case when it does not?

Comment: @EugeneMorozov ok, but I am not sure if this YT topic resolves my issue. There is a suggestion to add block name automatically to the endblock, but my struggle is to even get "endblock" by itself along with "block". Like I wrote up - I don't have any suggestions, only way to get "block" is to write "{%" and fill it with "block". I don't think there is a specific case in which this plugin didn't work. Maybe it had a problem with another one? Now, I also get those notifications, also in 2019.1 EAP version